# iOS dev: Problem with uploading UIImage to facebook album

Tags: ios, facebook, image-uploading

please check my code:

Here i'm trying to upload screenshot to facebook album, but that doesnt works

```
CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();    
self.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
CGImageRelease(screen);

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               self.image, @"picture",
                               nil];

[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                      andParams:params
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

self.image is ok, it is used in other parts of the code and everything looks nice. if i set up self.image for ex for [uiimage imagenamed@"example.png""] everything works nice. the different is that one uiimage exists on in memory and another both in memory and device.

what can bee wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. the problem was the wrong way of making a screenshot.